# Python Selenium loop keeps using the first URL, doesnt quit loop

Tags: python, selenium

I need to:

1. Open a new browser window.
2. Open a  from an array URL
3. Do some actions (not shown)
4. Quit the browser window
5. Loop until all URLs have been opened.

ACTUAL RESULT:
It keeps opening a new browser window, and only goes to the first URL (google.com), then closes it... and re-opens a new window at Google.com.  The loop is infinite and doesn't stop after 3 URLs in this example.

EXPECTED/DESIRED RESULT:
Loop through the URLs, and then stop the script once done (in this case, opening the browser 3 times, loading 3 different URLs, closing each browser)

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I tried

```
urlstoloop = ["http://google.com",
"http://yahoo.com",
"http://msn.com"]

i = 0
while i < len(urlstoloop):
  web = webdriver.Chrome()
  web.get(urlstoloop[i])





  CUSTOM CODE



  web.quit()



i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` instead of `while`:

```
for url in urlstoloop:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incremenitng `i` outside of the loop. This should be done inside the loop, so indent it in:

```
while i < len(urlstoloop):
    #something...
    i += 1
```

Also, as suggested by @Alderven, for this case it's better to use a for loop to iterate over the list of URLs. Just wanted to point out the mistake in your existing code.

Comment: Thanks! So the indentation in python seems to matter most?

Comment: Yes, Python is all about indentation! Think of indentation in Python like using curly braces in other languages. In your case, indentation determines which code is inside the loop, and which code is not.